# How to use 'America/New_York ' in At Time Zone in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, timezone

I have this piece of code that works fine in SQL. However I would like to use a different time zone format like  `'America/New_York'` instead of `'US Eastern Standard Time'`

```sql
SELECT TODATETIMEOFFSET(CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as datetime), -5) AT TIME ZONE 'US Eastern Standard Time'
FROM dual
```

Comment: Please tag your SQL engine as well.

Comment: Do u just want to replace the value of US Eastern Standard Time to America/New_York? I think 'SELECT TODATETIMEOFFSET(CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as datetime), -5) AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York' FROM dual' will do.

Comment: I am getting those time zones dynamically and there so many of them. America/New_York was just an example. I am getting the same error '555555 The Time zone parameter 'America/New-York' to AT TIME ZONE  clause is invalid'

Answer (score 3):

Presently, SQL Server only supports *Windows* time zone identifiers.  [You can vote for adding IANA time zone support here.](https://web.archive.org/web/20200814055434/https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/40198465-support-iana-time-zone-identifiers-with-at-time-zo)

In the meantime, you have options:

- In your application layer, you can convert the IANA time zone ID to the equivalent Windows time zone ID.  If you are using .NET, the simplest way is with my [TimeZoneConverter](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneConverter) library.  Otherwise, you can use the [CLDR mappings file](https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr/blob/master/common/supplemental/windowsZones.xml) manually, or any library implementation that is based on it.
- You could use my [SQL Server Time Zone Support](https://github.com/mj1856/SqlServerTimeZoneSupport) project, which uses custom tables and functions instead of the `AT TIME ZONE` statement.
- You could move all your time zone conversion logic into your application layer instead of the database.

Also, minor point - `US Eastern Standard Time` maps to `America/Indianapolis`.  You probably want `Eastern Standard Time`, which maps to `America/New_York`.